# Counting Subsets: Variable Sizes with Inclusion Constraint

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, combinatorial-proofs

If sets $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, with $|A| = k$ and $|B| = m$, where $k \leq m$, the task is to determine the total number of pairs $(A, B)$ where $A \subseteq B \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

For $m$ and $k$ fixed we get $\binom{m}{n}\binom{k}{m}$ pairs.
When $k$ varies and $m$ is fixed we get $\binom{0}{n}\binom{m}{n} + \binom{1}{n}\binom{m-1}{n-1} + \ldots + \binom{m}{n}\binom{0}{n-m} = 2^m \binom{m}{n}$. pairs

I have solved the problem when $k$ and $m$ are fixed and when only $m$ is fixed and I encountered difficulties when both $m$ and $k$ vary. I would really like to know what would also happen when we have $X_1 \subseteq X_2\subseteq... \subseteq X_n\subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, surely $k,m$ are fixed here, right?  In any case, I suggest adding your solution to the "fixed $m$" case to your post.

Comment: "*When both $m$ and $k$ vary*" for each $x\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ you will have either $x$ is in neither, $x\in B$ but not $A$, or $x$ is in both.  Three options for each of the $n$ elements, that gives a total of $3^n$.  For many such chained subsets, each value $x$ can either be in none, just the "top", the "top two", the "top three" or so on... for a total of $(a+1)^n$ where $a$ is the number of subsets being chained together.

Comment: If $B\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $|B|=m$, then $m\le n$, so $\binom mn$ is either $0$ or $1$. So that’s probably not what you meant?

Comment: @JMoravitz how do we get $3^n$. Does this include all the unordered and ordered number of pairs?

Comment: @joriki They use the different notation. $\binom nk$ becomes $\binom kn$.

Comment: @Aig: Interesting! I never saw that notation before. It’s not listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation) as an alternative notation. Is it widely used?

Comment: @joriki $C_n^k$ is very very common. I guess, $\binom kn$ is a halfway from $C_n^k$ to $\binom nk$.

Comment: @joriki it's mostly used in Europe.

Comment: "How do we get $3^n$?"  By rule of product.  $3\times 3\times\cdots \times 3 = 3^n$, we had 3 options for which combination of $A,B$ the element was in... either none, $B$ without $A$, or both.  "*Does this include all the unordered and ordered number of pairs*" You only asked about ordered pairs, and even if it was unordered it could be made ordered by the fact you specified that $A$ was a subset of $B$.

Comment: @JMoravitz How do we generalise for $X_1 \subseteq X_2\subseteq... \subseteq X_n\subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$

Comment: Again... for each $x$ it will necessarily be an element of none... an element of $X_n$ but none of $X_{n-1},X_{n-2},\dots,X_1$... an element of $X_{n}$ and $X_{n-1}$ but not of $X_{n-2},X_{n-3},\dots,X_1$, or so on up until being an element of all.  Repeat the question for each $x$.  Apply rule of product and conclude.  Note that this was already explained in my first comment